# Phonegap iOS certificates

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I build an InAppBrowser app for my website, on android works very well but after I exported the certificates I recive this error:

> Error - No codesigning identities found matching the provided provisioning profile: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (�app-dev�) were found. - You can fix this here

Does anyone have similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a common error encountered by PG developers.

You need to go through your iOS certificate signing process again, very carefully.

We've all had this!

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the build process, do not make mistakes

phonegap Build IPA

1.Upload your APP package zip to the site

[image]

2.click Builds Choice iOS Upload ios certificates provisioning profiles

[image]

3.Click the lock icon to enter the password

[enter image description here][3]

4.Click Rebuild Identification certificate construction IPA

[enter image description here][4]

5.After the completion of the compiler to download the IPA package

[enter image description here][5]